# How to properly change state in reducer so component can receive update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In reducer I have:

```
if (action.type === 'remove_item') {
      delete state.itemsList[action.itemId];
      return {
        ...state
      }
```

But now `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` can't see difference between:

```
this.props.items !== nextProps.items
```

I know that this happens because I changed state in reducer directly
 but don't know how to propagate this change now so nextProps will have new state data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
...state.itemsList.filter((_, index) => index !== action.itemId)
```

So you're not mutating the original state, instead creating a new array.

Answer (score 3):

It's not showing changes because state object is immutable and you are directly doing an operation on the immutable object.

Try this:

```
if (action.type === 'remove_item') {
      var list = state.itemsList.splice();
      list[action.itemId] = null
      return {
        ...state,
        itemsList: list,
      }
```

Cheers :)